# ERROR, when deleting multiple rows in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, checkbox, delete-row

my table name is inbox (id, date, message). and here is my code,
in view : inbox.php

```
<?php $attribute = array('class' => 'check', 'id' => 'myform'); ?>
<?php echo form_open('messages/remove_checked', $attribute); ?>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered tablesorter" id="mytable">
<tr><th width="5px" class=specalt ><input type="checkbox" id="select_all" name="select_all"/></th><th>date</th><th>Message</th></tr>
<?php foreach($inbox as $row) : ?>
<tr>
<td width="5px" class=spec><input type="checkbox" name="cntact[]" class="check" value="<?php echo $row->ID; ?>"></td>
<td><? echo $row->Date; ?></td>
<td><? echo $row->Message; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```

i add this one to check all the checkbox,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#select_all').click(function() {
    var c = this.checked;
    $(':checkbox').prop('checked',c);
});
});
</script>
```

my controller : messages.php

```
function remove_checked()
    {
        //validation rules
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cntact[]', 'Private Contact', 'required|xss_clean'); 

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
        {
           $remove = "No <strong>Data</strong> deleted!";
            $this -> json_response(FALSE, $remove); 
            redirect("messages/inbox");  
        }
        else //success
        {
            $checked_messages = $this->input->post('cntact'); //selected messages
            $this->Mysms_model->delete_checked($checked_messages);

            //redirect to 
            redirect("messages/inbox");                          
        }

}
```

and my model : Mysms_model.php

```
function delete_checked($cntact) 
    {
        $this->db->where_in('ID', $cntact)
                ->delete('inbox');
        return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;
    }
```

the problem is, when i run this code, i found an error.
"DELETE FROM `inbox` WHERE `ID` IN ('on', 'on')".
so, what s on? it should number of ID, any answer?
thank you.

Comment: Seems ok to me. Basically `on` comes when we don't have any `value` attribute in `checkbox input tag`. But you have a value attribute here, hence the error is unexpected.

Comment: Using the inspector or view source check that the value is actually being echo'd correctly.

Comment: ok, thanks .. i hve fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not meant to be an answer to the question, however, I just wanted to show you an alternative way to write your view using codeigniters built in libraries and helpers:

```
<?php 
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('table');

echo form_open('messages/remove_checked', array('class' => 'check', 'id' => 'myform'));

$this->table->set_template(array('table_open' => '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered tablesorter" id="mytable">'));
$this->table->set_heading(
    array('width' => '5px', 'class' => 'specalt', 'data' => form_checkbox(array('id' => 'select_all', 'name' => 'select_all'))),
    'date',
    'message'
);

foreach ($inbox as $row) {
    $this->table->add_row(
        array('width' => '5px', 'class' => 'spec', 'data' => form_checkbox(array('class' => 'check', 'name' => 'cntact[]', 'value' => $row->ID))),
        $row->Date,
        $row->Message
    );
}

echo $this->table->generate();
echo form_close();
```